# Как получить синхронный ответ от async метода?

Tags: c#, tpl, async-await

Есть метод, который обращается к серверу, а потому использует примерно такой вызов:

```
public static async Task<Page> GetPageAsync(Uri url)
{
    var webClient = new CookieClient();
    await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
    return new Page(result, webClient.ResponseUri);
}
```

Метод работает, но он обычно используется в других, и выше получается так:

```
public static async Task<string> GetName(Uri uri)
{
  var name = string.Empty;
  var document = new HtmlDocument();
  var page = await Page.GetPageAsync(uri);
  document.LoadHtml(page.Content);
  var nameNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title");
  return WebUtility.HtmlDecode(nameNode.InnerHtml);
}
```

Суть проблемы - `GetName(uri).Result` молча висит и ничего не делает, при попытке вызвать таким образом метод в обычном коде. Таска при этом находится в состоянии `WaitingForActivation`.

Можно вызывать `async` методы в синхронном коде или надо писать аналогичный синхронный код отдельными методами?

Comment: А не вызываете ли вы ваш `Task.Result` в UI-потоке случайно?

Comment: @VladD, в нём самом. Всмысле, где то ещё парой уровней выше вызов из UI. Проблема то в чём?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас deadlock.

Смотрите, в чём проблема.

Вы блокируетесь в ожидании `Task`'а в UI-потоке. Это значит, что когда вы пишете `GetName(uri).Result`, ваш UI-поток висит в ожидании окончания `Task`'а `GetName(uri)`.

Почему же `GetName(uri)` не завершается? Смотрим на `GetPageAsync(Uri url)`. Он начинает выполняться тоже в UI-потоке. Код `await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)` уходит в ожидание, и когда загрузка завершится, должен получить управление. Это значит, что тот поток, где был получен сигнал об окончании загрузки, запускает остаток метода в UI-потоке при помощи `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` или чего-то подобного.

Но UI-поток блокирован! И ждёт, пока завершится вызов `.Result`. Поэтому он не может отработать хвост метода.

Итак, что делать в этом случае? Есть две рекомендации, и любая из них решает проблему (но следовать стоит обеим).

Итак, рекомендация номер 1: в «библиотечном» коде, наподобие `GetPageAsync` или `GetName`, вам не обязательно всё время возвращаться в UI-поток. Вы можете сообщить это системе при помощи следующей конструкции:

```
result = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url)
                        .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
```

При этом после окончания ожидания в `await` код не будет перебрасываться в UI-поток, но вам это и не нужно в этом методе.

Все «библиотечные» процедуры (которым не нужен UI-контекст) стоит оформлять с `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Рекомендация номер 2: Никогда не блокируйтесь в UI-потоке! Если асинхронная функция будет выполняться долго, ваш UI зависнет, а это плохо. Старайтесь протягивать `async` до конца. Это вовсе не сложно, кстати.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Stephen Cleary: *Don't Block on Async Code*](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: По первой рекомендации - не помогает. Всмысле, я добавил везде по стеку `ConfigureAwait(false)`, но по моему он до их выполнения дойти даже не успевает.

Comment: @Monk: Значит, где-то по дороге забыли. Или у вас в каком-то из методов два `await`. Перепроверьте!

Comment: @Monk: Можно проверять по одному: сначала вызовите из UI-потока `GetPageAsync(url).Result`, если это работает, то `GetName(uri).Result` и т. д.

Comment: @Monk: На крайний случай, есть ещё костыль: `Task.Run(() => GetPageAsync(url)).Result`. Но это настолько неправильно, что я не буду вносить в ответ (чтобы не копипастили).

Comment: Я этим костылем пока сверху прикрылся, чтобы не зависеть от UI потока. А с остальным пока пытаюсь понять, где же надо было явно создать таску, чтобы не в UI потоке работать. Проблема видимо в этом, теоретически.

Comment: @Monk: Ну вы бы всё же протянули `ConfigureAwait` :) А почему не полностью async? Это хороший путь.

Comment: >А почему не полностью async - потому что фактически надо почти все методы на это переводить. Много и долго, явно не сегодня.

Comment: @Monk: Ну это да, но запланируйте на будущее. Оно того стоит, и приложение не будет подвисать.

Comment: @Monk не все методы. Только в функционале что работает с неблокирующим I/O. В остальном выгоды скорее всего не будет.

Comment: @vitidev: С другой стороны, `Task<...>` — удобный интерфейс для длительной операции. А что именно под капотом, вполне может быть вызывающему коду и неинтересно.

Comment: @VladD, не получилось прокидывать asnyc до самого верха. Оказалось, что некоторые конструкторы вынуждены делать запросы, а они идут через цепочку и тогда надо уже делать разные цепочки... ересь короче, тупо проброс точно не спасает =)

Comment: @Monk: То, что конструктор должен делать запросы — неправильно. Конструктор обязан отрабатывать быстро, а запрос — штука медленная. Каждая медленная функция должна быть по идее `Task`'ом, но конструктор, понятно, таким быть не может. Значит, нужен рефакторинг.

Comment: @VladD, нужен, кто ж спорит, только у меня это внешнее ограничение, класс без запроса невалидный и нигде использоваться не должен. Учитывая, как всё завязано, буду скорее откатывать изменения по асинхронным запросам, слишком они друг от друга зависят.

Comment: @Monk: А какая проблема? Сделайте конструктор приватным, напишите async-фабрику, которая будет создавать и правильно инициализировать экземпляр.

Comment: @VladD, раз уж нужна фабрика, буду искать способы сделать её удобной с учетом наследования. Время, всё упирается во время. Потом как нибудь снова попробую async =)

Comment: @Monk: Да ну, там ничего сложного. Вот: http://pastebin.com/fV9RfG8w было `X_old`, стало `X_new`. И везде `new X_old()` меняете на `await X_new.Create()`. Не пугайтесь страшного слова «фабрика» :)

Comment: @Monk: С учётом наследования/иерархии классов: http://pastebin.com/SGEaaCX5

Comment: @VladD, где то сторонние либы требуют открытых конструкторов, так что придется думать, что делать.

Comment: @Monk: Ну, если либа требует открытого конструктора, тогда упс. Настучите по ушам авторам либы, они не правы.